# AMC1200BDUBR Gain is 4 instead of 8

Tags: amplifier, voltage-measurement, gain, isolated

I want to measure grid voltage with AMC1200b. I used a resistor voltage divider and I lowered grid voltage from 110v(rms) to 110mv(rms). I fed the 110mv(rms) signal to AMC1200b (for the first side of AMC1200b I used a 5v power supply and for the second side I used an isolated 3.3v power supply). The problem is, based on the datasheet, the gain should be fixed and 8, but it is 4 and I am losing some resolution for sampling.
I also used a filter for the shunt resistor like it was in the datasheet( 2*12ohm resistors + 330pF capacitor).

Could you please let me know what's wrong with the circuit?

Comment: You do know the output is differential? If you take only one output it may seem as gain is 4.

Comment: 2Vpp/0.25Vpp =8 differential also the RC filter was for a much lower R shunt current resistor, not a voltage divider. What is your shunt R value?

Comment: Voltage divider = voltage measurement, Shunt = current measurement, Show your schematics and what are you measuring,

Comment: Hi @Jeroen3, yes I do, and I connected the negative output to the ground directly

Comment: Hi @TonyStewartEE75, it is 12 ohm

Comment: Why would you ever short the negative output to ground? That reduces your gain in half and short circuits the output driver at 20mA.

Comment: Hi @MarkoBuršič unfortunately I don't have the schematic now

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 oh is it the problem? if I disconnect it is it going to be 8 again?

Comment: no, you need a differential amplifier to use both outputs if you wanted 8x

Answer (score 1):

> Hi @Jeroen3, yes I do, and I connected the negative output to the ground directly

The AMC1200 has a differential output. Gain 8 is achieved by using a differential input. Using only one output will seem to have half of total gain.
Shorting the output is not recommended.

If you only have a single ended ADC you need to convert it with a differential amplifier.
Or you can sample both signals with your single-ended ADC and subtract them in software.
You do get some error if you can't sample simultaneously.